# How do I add a custom ApplicationShortcut in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, shortcut

I have the following code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    mUi(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    mUi->setupUi(this);
    this->setFixedSize(this->width(), this->height());

    StyleUi();

    auto closeAct = new QAction(this);
    closeAct->setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+O"));
    connect(closeAct, SIGNAL(activated()), this, SLOT(close()));
    closeAct->setShortcutContext(Qt::ApplicationShortcut);
    addAction(closeAct);
}
```

The last 5 lines define a QAction with a shortcut created from the sequence Ctrl+O, connects the QAction the the slot Close(). I've found this example here on stackoverflow and several other documentation sites describe what I want to do as such. However, I am not getting anywhere with this. My program doesn't close when I hit Ctrl+O. Any suggestions on where I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create it by using the multiple arguments constructor for [QKeySequence](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html).

like this:

```
QShortcut *shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_O), this);
shortcut->setContext(Qt::ApplicationShortcut);
```

And try this to get QShortcut signal activated:

```
connect(shortcut, &QShortcut::activated, this, &MainApp::activeShortcut);

void MainApp::activeShortcut()
{
    this->close();
}
```

This is a sample project for your question on [github download here.](https://github.com/FarhadProfessional/QShortcut)